# kubernetes crashloopbackoff only after second restart onward

Tags: kubernetes

My aim is to have an `autoscaled` set of pods, defined as below, that process a dynamic Redis queue. The container process currently is just a python script that takes the next value from the queue, and exits.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: job

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: job
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: job
      labels:
        tier: job
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job
        image: job
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
```

I am having a hard time understanding the restart behaviour: here is the output from watching a pod for a while.

```
NAME                   READY STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
job-6465767d94-vh667   0/1   Completed          0     13s
job-6465767d94-vh667   1/1   Running            1     16s
job-6465767d94-vh667   0/1   Completed          1     27s
job-6465767d94-vh667   0/1   CrashLoopBackOff   1     38s
job-6465767d94-vh667   1/1   Running            2     40s
job-6465767d94-vh667   0/1   Completed          2     50s
job-6465767d94-vh667   0/1   CrashLoopBackOff   2     63s
```

As you can see, it restarts fine after first run, then enters a `CrashLoopBackOff` state before restarting. The problem with this is that each "crash" the internal timer before the pod is restarted is increased.

To run it, I use:

```
kubectl apply -f job.yaml
kubectl autoscale deployment job-wq-2 --min=3 --max=10 --cpu-percent=20
```

Some further details:

`kubectl describe`

[image]

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl describe jobs/job`. And logs for this job?

Comment: @Crou added the kubectl describe, the logs are just my print calls then nothing when I call exit

Comment: How are you completing the `Deployment`?

Comment: I am not aware how to do that and my quick googling has failed me

Comment: What I mean is, after your python script process the Redis queue what happens next?

Comment: the script finishes with exit(0) and then the container dies I guess because the run command is just python worker.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you either rewrite the script, so it does not `End` but it waits for another thing to process, or use `Kind: Job`.

You can follow this Kubernetes documentation regarding [Jobs - Run to Completion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming you have already seen [Fine Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/)?

Comment: I can of course make it run forever, but then it doesn't scale down ever right? I tried jobs but the problem there was the unknown queue size, that tutorial you linked of course is what I started with but it didn't fit either and some research online suggested maybe use Job for this

Comment: For this I think you should consider [Parallel Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#parallel-jobs)